# Can byte-code manipulation change the return type of a Java method at run-time?

Tags: java, proxy, javassist, cglib, bytecode-manipulation

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this with byte-code manipulation:

```
public class Foo {
    public int getBlah() {
       return 1;
    }
}

public void hi(int x) {
    System.out.println("hi: " + x);
}

public void hi(String x) {
    System.out.println("wow: " + x);
}
```

Now I want to call:

```
hi(foo.getBlah());
```

and invoke the overloading hi method for the String parameter.

Comment: What are you really up to? If it's only about Strings and Integer, you can just parse/convert those arguments and return types. You should try to state your problem instead of limiting yourself to bytecode manipulation - it's often not necessary to use that.

Comment: I want to divert from one method to another at run-time, even thought through the return type of my getBlah() method this looks impossible.

Comment: What byte-code library do you plan on using? And this is very possible, I've done similar things before.

Comment: @Austin You are kidding, right? :) Javassist or CGLIB, you choose.

Comment: @JohnPristine Kidding about what? Those aren't the only libraries out there.

Comment: @Austin: I was asking you if you can really do what you said. :) Looks impossible to me. I am still waiting for your answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you handle a *flagged value* on `hi(int x)`? If yes you could do something like this:

```
public void hi(int x) {
    if (x == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        String newParam = getTheParamFromProxySomehow();
        hi(newParam);
        return;
    }    
    System.out.println("hi: " + x);
}
```

It is basically:

- Intercept through a proxy the `getBlah()` method
- Save (in a `ThreadLocal`?) whatever String parameter you want to pass to the overloaded `hi` method
- Return the flagged value such as `0`, `-1` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`
- Do the trick above

It is a little hacky and it looks best when you don't have a primitive so you can use `null` as your flagged value. Hopefully someone has a better answer. :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please note that you can use backticks to put code inline to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can change the return type, it would not solve the problem. The compiler decides at compile time which implementation of an overloaded method is called. Changing the return type would not change the method that is called. The bytecode would still call the `hi(int x)` method with a `String` and probably cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. But to get your imagination going, take a look at [my old blog about operation overload](http://www.jroller.com/eu/entry/operation_overloading_in_java) in Java with some help of [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) framework. Here is a little example from there:

```
  BigInteger val = Evaluator.evaluate(new Evaluation() {
        public int evaluate(int x, int y) {
          return x - y;
        }
      }, new BigInteger("2"), new BigInteger("3"));
```

Comment: I simply answered your question. Did you look at the blog post I linked?